# Prove that $\left| \int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x^2+1}\right|\le \frac{\pi}{12e}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that $\displaystyle\left| \int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x^2+1}dx\right|\le \frac{\pi}{12e}$

I tried comparing this integral with $\displaystyle\int \frac{e^{-x}}{x^2} dx$ but this integrates out to something greater than $\frac{\pi}{12e}$. Any hints would be appreciated, as this is an exercise I'm working on to review calculus. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(Very big) hint:**$$
\int_1^\sqrt{3} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \dfrac{\pi}{12}
$$